# Mock ResponseEntity<?> inside Rest Controller class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, junit5

I am trying to return ResponseEntity object by mocking service. Below is my code

```
    HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
    header.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    
    LinkedHashMap<Object, Object> mockResponseObj = new LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>();
    ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    LinkedHashMap<Object, Object> nestedObj = new LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>();
    nestedObj.put("key1", "val1");
    list.add(nestedObj);
    mockResponseObj.put("data", list);

    ResponseEntity<Object> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(mockResponseObj, header, HttpStatus.OK);
    
    Mockito.when(myService.getDataListByAccount(Mockito.any(MyRequestBody.class))).thenReturn(responseEntity);
```

I am getting the following compiler error

**The method thenReturn(ResponseEntity<capture#1-of ?>) in the type OngoingStubbing<ResponseEntity<capture#1-of ?>> is not applicable for the arguments (ResponseEntity)**

Inside my service class

```
public ResponseEntity<?> getDataListByAccount(MyRequestBody obj) {
    ResponseEntity<?> transactionHistoryResponse = null;
    try {
        historyResponse = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, obj, Object.class);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new MyCustomException(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Internal  Error Occurred"), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(historyResponse.getBody(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: can you show your `getDataListByAccount` method?

Comment: @AmirSchnell: I added the code for service class method.

Comment: I would guess there is a mismatch between `ResponseEntity<?>` and `ResponseEntity<Object>`. Try to make them both the same and see if that does the trick

Comment: @AmirSchnell: that worked thanks. But in our project everywhere ResponseEntity<?> is getting used. any solution for that?

Comment: The best would be not to use it. Since these are actual implementations, that you have, you shouild know, what is returned and define it as it is. And don't use `ResponseEntity<Object>` either, because that doesn't add any more meaning. For this test you could use `ResponseEnity<?>` in the test case itself, I think, so you don't have to change the contract of the method.